# Angular + Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I'm currently experimenting with Browserify + Angular and I've stumbled into a weird issue. I've created a file within a subdir for my controller called `controllers/start-controller.js`.`

In my app.js file I have a local variable that references the controllers:

`var controllers = require('./controllers/');`

Within `controllers/` is an index.js file that references the start-controller:

`require('./start-controller');`

And then back in my app.js, to call the controller I have the following:

`app.controller('StartController', ['$scope', controllers.StartController]);`

**The problem:**

With the current setup, StartController isn't recognised and Angular throws [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=StartController&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined). However, if I change the local variable to include start-controller directly:

`var controllers = require('./controllers/start-controller');`

Then this works fine but this isn't really what I'm after. I'd like to be able to reference the controllers within controllers/index.js. Is app.controller missing something in the call to StartController which is why it can't recognise it?

Comment: By "StartController isn't recognised" do you mean that `controllers.StartController` is undefined? Can you create a small example?  I cannot reproduce any issues on my side.

Comment: I believe @RickvanMook's answer is the correct solution, but posting `index.js` would be a lot more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the contents of your `index` and `start-controller` files but it looks like you need to export `StartController` in your index file.

Try to this in your `controllers/index.js`

```
exports.StartController = require('./start-controller');
```

Answer (score 0):

James Halliday (substack, creator of browserify) has been hard at work coming up with the browserify handbook: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook

This resource is excellent. It goes really deep into how requires work and resolve dependencies. It is by far the best resource I have ever seen on the subject. Perhaps if you (or anyone else landing on this question with a similar problem) give it a read, the answer might jump out at you.

I know it's not a direct answer to your question, but I only recently found this resource, and I wish I knew it existed earlier.

For an introduction to browserify, I recommend watching this tagtree video: http://tagtree.tv/browserify-an-intro?share_code=uncoopered-inspirer﻿

Comment: While this is a great reference and very helpful, it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something awesome about Angular is how modular it is by design.  The modularity also lends itself to unit testing for each module.

Inside your index.js file you could establish an Angular module:

```
module.exports = angular.module('app.controllers', [
  require('./start-controller').name
]);
```

And then inside your start-controller.js file:

```
  module.exports = angular.module('app.controllers.startController', [])

  .controller('StartCtrl', ['$scope',

    function($scope, ) {

    }
  ]);
```

Now when you want to test just the start controller you have it isolated inside angular already.

At this point if you want to add this module to a larger app, for instance your root app, you'd do the exact same process at the top level:

```
 module.exports = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router', // Third party library that we've pulled in with an earlier require()
    require('./controllers').name
  ]);
```

And then inside your index.html file:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js">
```